# Linux i2c touch device driver probe not be called

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c, touchscreen, device-tree

I try to add focaltech touch driver to my board, the `fts_ts_init()` is worked, but the `->probe()` not be called, I do not why. CONFIG_OF is opened.

## Driver code：

```c
static const struct i2c_device_id fts_ts_id[] = {
    {FTS_DRIVER_NAME, 0},
    {}
};
static const struct of_device_id fts_dt_match[] = {
    {.compatible = "focaltech,fts", },
    {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, fts_dt_match);

static struct i2c_driver fts_ts_driver = {
    .probe = fts_ts_probe,
    .remove = fts_ts_remove,
    .driver = {
        .name = FTS_DRIVER_NAME,
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
#if defined(CONFIG_PM) && FTS_PATCH_COMERR_PM
        .pm = &fts_dev_pm_ops,
#endif
        .of_match_table = of_match_ptr(fts_dt_match),
    },
    .id_table = fts_ts_id,
};

static int __init fts_ts_init(void)
{
    int ret = 0;

    FTS_FUNC_ENTER();
    ret = i2c_add_driver(&fts_ts_driver);
    printk("[FTS_TS] ret=%d\n", ret);
    if (ret)
        FTS_ERROR("Focaltech touch screen driver init failed!");
    FTS_FUNC_EXIT();
    return ret;
}
module_init(fts_ts_init);
```

## Device Tree Source:

```dts
i2c4: i2c@0x10054000 {
    compatible = "ingenic,x2000-i2c";
    reg = <0x10054000 0x1000>;
    interrupt-parent = <&core_intc>;
    interrupts = <IRQ_I2C4>;
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    status = "okay";

    focaltech@38{ 
        compatible = "focaltech,fts";   
        reg = <0x38>;                   
        interrupt-parent = <&gpa>;              
        interrupts = <3 0x2>;

        focaltech,reset-gpio = <&gpa 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW >;
        focaltech,irq-gpio = <&gpa 3 0x2 >;     
        focaltech,max-touch-number = <2>;           
        focaltech,display-coords =  <0 0 800 480>;   

        status = "okay";
    };
};
```

I try to write the node in /, and use a simple paltform drvier, `of_match_table` is the same, `->probe()` is called.

Comment: Are you looking at the kernel messages, what is printed for your hardware? is there any error, or failure reported?

Comment: What does "opened" mean in regard to `CONFIG_OF`? And what's the value of `FTS_DRIVER_NAME`? Ah, and where is `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE()` for the I²C ID table? You have it only for OF, but not for I²C...

Comment: #define FTS_DRIVER_NAME                     "fts_ts"

Comment: "opened" mean CONFIG_OF has been selected in the .config.

Comment: kernel message show `fts_ts_init()` has been called ,but  `fts_ts_probe()` not called.  I want to know will probe execute if the I2C device does not respond?

Comment: `[ 6916.392424] [FTS_TS]fts_ts_init: Enter` 

`[ 6916.396496] [FTS_TS]fts_ts_init: Exit(2206)`

Comment: 1. Add `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, ...)` for I²C ID table. 2. Rename `"fts_ts"` to `"fts"` in the I²C ID table (or update the `FTS_DRIVER_NAME` to be `"fts"`). 3. For the debugging purposes use `initcall_debug` in the kernel command line. 4. I recommend to drop use of `of_match_ptr()`, just use its parameter directly.

Comment: Your code missed `->remove()` callback, ah, I see it's mentioned, but not shown in the code excerpt. Instead of `module_init()` and `module_exit()` I recommend to use `module_i2c_driver()`.